# Reading XML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
Here's the XML:
```

```js
  <employees>
  <employee ID="ABC00" lastName="Smith" firstName="Bill">
    <licenses>
      <license State="KS" liccat="Land0003" type="Landscape Architect"                 includeInProposal="Y" expiration="12/31/2016"/>
      <license State="MO" liccat="Land0003" type="Landscape Architect" includeInProposal="Y" expiration="12/31/2015"/>
      <license State="NE" liccat="Land0003" type="Landscape Architect" includeInProposal="N" expiration=""/>
    </licenses>
  </employee>
  <employee ID="ADM01" lastName="Smith" firstName="Sam">
    <licenses>
      <license> State="MO" liccat="Prof0008" type="Professional Engineer" includeInProposal="Y" expiration="12/31/2016"/>
      <license State="KS" liccat="Prof0008" type="Professional Engineer" includeInProposal="Y" expiration="04/30/2017"/>
      <license State="OK" liccat="Prof0008" type="Professional Engineer" includeInProposal="Y" expiration="08/31/2016"/>
    </licenses>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

```
Here's the code: 

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
       url: "NLicense.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {
            alert('Read the file');

            $(xml).find('employees').each(function(){
            var emp =  $(this).attr("lastName"); /* read the root */
            var images = $('licenses license',this).map(function() {
                  return 'hello' +  $(this).children('State').text() + " " ;
            }).get().join('');
            console.log(images);


Here's the problem:
```

I am trying extract the license information in the XML file, however if you look at the word 'hello' that is all that gets returned.  For example, in the first XML entry I get "hello hello hello".

Thanks,

Comment: attributes are not a child

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but it looks like you need to change this line:

```
return 'hello' +  $(this).children('State').text() + " " ;
```

to this

```
return 'hello' +  $(this).attr('State') + " " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('employee').each(function(){
     var emp =  $(this).attr("lastName"); /* read the root */
     var images = $('licenses license',this).map(function() {
         return 'hello ' +  $(this).attr('State') + " " ;
     }).get().join('');
     console.log(images);
});
```

replace `$(xml).find('employees')` with `$(xml).find('employee')` and `$(this).children('State').text()` with `$(this).attr('State')`

Comment: if an answer helped then please upvote/mark as answered :)